# How to get street view using OpenLayers with Bing map

Tags: bing-maps, openlayers

I am looking into solution for displaying street view using OpenLayers with Bing map. I couldn't find any examples on OpenLayers website. They have examples which displays satellite map using different imaginary set.

Is it possible to use OpenLayers to display street view using Bing Map? If yes then how.

Comment: do you mean streetside?

Comment: @nmtoken, Yes StreetSide. I can see it on Bing Map. I wanted to know is it possible to use Open Layers and Bing Map as source to display Street Side

Comment: Streetside is served as tiles https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/getting-streetside-tiles-from-imagery-metadata but the grid and projection will be different to map or aerial tiles, so you would probably want to swap to a new OpenLayers map object, and you would need to create a custom grid and tileUrlFunction based on the JSON response.  It would probably be easier to use the Bing Maps API directly.instead of OpenLayers for the second map.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks. I think your idea of using Bing MAP for the second map instead of OpenLayers looks good to me. I will try that.